# Pulling in Matrix cells in Records tag pair using Link Vault

Tags: matrix

I need a little help on a project that's using the addon Link Vault from Masuga Design (http://masugadesign.com/software/link-vault/) in conjunction with Matrix.

The site has a channel called ‘Topics’, each topic has an entry that has a Matrix field with the columns ‘Link’ and ‘File’. The topic pages are setup so they list all the files per topic entry from the Matrix field.

The field is a Matrix field called 'download' and has the cells 'File Name' and 'File'.

We're using this code so far:

```
{exp:link_vault:records limit="5"}<a href="{directory}{file_name}">Download</a>{/exp:link_vault:records}
```

I can get the file to link up and work, but not pass the 'File Name' field from a row to the template. The download count also needs to be unique to each Matrix row, too (not covering all files from the single entry.)

Comment: Hey Oliver - are you able to get Matrix to output its data without Link Vault involved?  Isolating the pieces may help us uncover what is going on here. :)

Comment: Lisa, ended up getting it sorted. Through a combination of an add-on update and what turned out to be my misreading of some of the documentation. Completely missed defining the Link Vault custom fields to be able to specify them in the Matrix rows in the first place... So this one was definitely user error.

Comment: Awesome, Oliver.  Please post this as an answer and accept it?  And thank you so much for following up and letting me know what happened.  I've not used Link Vault but I'll try to remember if this comes up again!

Answer (score 1):

Ended up sorting this out...

Through a combination of an add-on update and what turned out to be my misreading of some of the documentation. Completely missed defining the Link Vault custom fields to be able to specify them in the Matrix rows in the first place... So this one was definitely user error.